# what's best way to handle xml in mws

Tags: python, amazon-mws

I am using python.

For feeds api you need to submit an xml file. How do I convert it from xsd files in python?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [GenerateDS](http://pythonhosted.org/generateDS/). It provides tools you need.